# Transfer from excel 2016 to 356

Tags: excel, vba, office365, transfer

I have problems with transfer solutions from Excel 2016 to Office 365. Both office is 32-bit.
I have userform with I am going use for: finding dubbels, show results in ListBox or Add new value to "DataBase.Sheet". The same file is working with 2016, but not 356.
I checked:

- Trust Center settings - the same
- References in VBA
- Add MSCOMCT2.OCX for Data Pickers (6)

What is wrong? Here are 2 codes with problem "Complile error: Can't find project or library":

1. Looking for exist value- debbug stopped on `Set cell`:

   ```
   Set cell = Selection.Find(What:=FindDMC, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
               lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
               MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
   ```
2. Looking value and display row in ListBox- debbug stopped on `CountResult = ListBoxResult.ListCount` :

   ```
    Const SearchColx As Long = 3
    Dim datax As Variant
    datax = Sheets("DataBase").Range("B1").CurrentRegion
    Dim i As Long: i = UBound(datax, 1)
    Dim j As Long: j = UBound(datax, 2)
    Dim results() As Variant
    ReDim Preserve results(1 To j, 1 To i)
    Dim x As Long, jx As Integer, n As Long
    For x = 1 To i
     If datax(x, SearchColx) = FindPB.Value Then
            n = n + 1
            For jx = 1 To j
                results(jx, n) = datax(x, jx)
            Next
        End If
    Next x
    With ListBoxResult
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 33
        .ColumnWidths = "0;195;120;120;100;0;0;0;0;60;0;0;0;80;0;0;0;0;0;80;80;60;0;0;40;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"
            If n Then
            ReDim Preserve results(1 To j, 1 To n)
            .Column = results
        End If
    End With CountResult = ListBoxResult.ListCount
   ```

Comment: Do you have any VBA references flagged as "missing" in the VBA Project?

Comment: no, information with reference is missing, but I solved problem. Someone created this workbook on my company installed reference for internal SW and this was root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UowZytKPVc
Method number 1.

The root cause was reference with which was not used but not transfer from one computer to second. Just click check box off.